# Capybara poltergeist phantomjs JavascriptError on Audio

Tags: capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm getting an exception:

> Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError

And a debug output:

> "args"=>[[{"message"=>"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Audio"

[Here's what I found when researching the error:](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-244870.html?s=5c41aabec2b71023a193652e607c65b7)

> This issue is due to sencha 2.0 using phantomjs in order to resolve
>   dependencies. Phantomjs does not support the HTML5 Audio API.

Question is: How do I ignore javascript errors for javascript Audio type when using capybara/poltergeist ?

I tried

```
visit "/"
page.execute_script "var Audio= function(){ return { load: function(){}, play: function(){} } }"
```

But error is thrown at the visit method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phantomjs doesn't support `Audio` as specified in the git documentation [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Supported-Web-Standards)

I had the same problem and also tried to follow your approach using the code like the one you described, but without using `var` so it will be defined globally.

```
page.execute_script "Audio= function(){ return { load: function(){}, play: function(){} } }"
```

I tested it with the inspector `page.driver.debug` and it was defining `Audio` in phantomjs correctly, the problem then was that, it wasn't being executed before it was needed.

Therefore, my approach was to add a check to verify `Audio` is defined before actually using it with a function in my actual code. This is an example of the function I have:

```
getAudioObject = function(file_path){
  if (typeof Audio !== "undefined" && Audio !== null) {
    audioObj = new Audio(file_path);
    audioObj.loop = true;
    return audioObj;
  }
}
```

That was my solution and it worked for me. I hope that this will help you too.

Comment: I remember doing something similar. Instead of putting my Audio code into an if, I defined an empty Audio globally in my code if the browser doesn't define it. But yours is a perfectly legit answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To properly define global variable before any resource script was initialized use "onInitialized" handler.

Comment: Yes, that works for plain PhantomJS scripts, but I don't think this works for capybara.